# Show comment buttons to low rep users and explain why they can't (yet) comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, new-users

I am new and have very little reputation. It took me a while to find the comment buttons, only after I searched in Google I found out that certain tasks require an amount of reputation.

Why not show the action buttons to keep persistence, and show the information that you can't use them yet on click or on mouse over?

Comment: That's an excellent idea.

Comment: This makes sense; I remember being confused by this on SuperUser when I first found the SE network. (Personally, I'd prefer that the comment button just return a message.)

Comment: @NeilFein having a message on click might not work well because you can comment on your answers and on your questions. So if the first one you try to comment on one is not your own you may not realize that you can comment on ones that are.

Comment: Yes, don't *hide* things - explain them. +1.

Comment: Sure it would. When clicking on the comment button on any question or answer that's not yours: "You can only comment on your own questions and answers until you reach 50 rep on this site. Keep asking and answering questions and you'll be there in no time!"

Comment: @NeilFein actually "your own questions and answers" is not 100% accurate. You can comment on answers to your questions. So its "you can only comment on your answers, questions or answers to your questions ..." Probably too much text and the users won't read it. Interestingly this came up on UI.Stackexchange. http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/20168/2234

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter - Good point. So: "You can't comment on this until you reach 50 rep on this site" or similar wording.

Comment: +1 Congrats! you can now add comments anywhere in Meta!